# Why computing similarity with gensim needs the size of the dictionary?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim

In order to use the `gensim.similarities.docsim.Similarity` class to compute similarities between words, one need to provide the corpus and the size of the dictionary.

In my case, the corpus are the word vectors computed using a word2vec model.

I wonder why `gensim` needs the size of the dictionary? And also, if it needs here the size of the dictionary used to create the word2vec model, or the size of the dictionary of the corpus, for which I want to compute the similarities.

Comment: Hm, I probably just answered the question myself. I guess it's because Similarity expects a sparse vector as a list of (index, value) pairs. In `MatrixSimilarity` the `num_features` parameter is optional. right?

Answer (score 1):

Note that you don't **need** to use `gensim.similarities.docsim.Similarity` to calculate word-to-word similarities.

There are individual methods on the word-vector supporting objects for doing things like calculating similarity between 2 words (`model.similarity(wordA, wordB)`) or getting the list of most-similar 'neighbor' words (`model.most_similar(target_word)`).